# Javascript: Copy all S3 items from one bucket to other

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am  trying to copy all the items (files and folders) from one `s3 bucket` to other. I am running this on `AWS Lambda` so, sync is not a good option for me as it may take more then 5 minutes to execute a sync command. Here is my JS code:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var sourceBucket = "source-bucket";
    var destinationBucket = "destination-bucket";
    var objectKey = "/";
    var copySource = encodeURI(sourceBucket + objectKey);
    var copyParams = { Bucket: destinationBucket, CopySource: copySource, Key: objectKey
};

s3.copyObject(copyParams, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log("S3 object copy successful.");
    }
});
};
```

Somehow, this code isn't working. There are 2 things that I want to implement here.

- Copy all data from one bucket to other
- Once I implement the copy operation, I will run this code periodically every day, creating a new folder to "destination bucket", and copy all the data everyday in the newly created folder.

I would really appreciate, if someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

If it takes longer than 5 minutes to run `aws s3 sync` then it may still fail in Lambda using Node.js. There's no magic bullet by using the Node.js API for AWS. If you really need to run longer than 5 minutes, there are strategies for detecting if your function is about to run out of time. See "context.getRemainingTimeInMillis" here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-context.html

But to answer your question, you need to first list all the objects in the bucket using `s3.listObjectsV2` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectsV2-property).

Once you have an array of objects, you need to iterate through and copy each of them with `s3.copyObject` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#copyObject-property)

Your code right now is attempting to get a single object from the source bucket with key `/` which does not exist. S3 buckets are not really directories. They have some directory-like behavior, especially in the online web console, but really it's just a collection of key-value pairs.